# Remove Duplicate node in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to write a XSLT in which I can remove duplicate node while translating.
In the below message since the temperature code is same for 1 and 3 node, it is duplicate for me.

The sample Input Message which I am using is

```
    <document>
    <party>
        <gtin>1000909090</gtin>
        <pos>
            <attrGroupMany name="temperatureInformation">
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">STORADE</attr>
                    <attrQual name="maximumTemperature" qual="FAH">80</attrQual>
                    <attrQual name="minimumTemperature" qual="ABC">10</attrQual>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">HANDLING</attr>
                    <attrQual name="maximumTemperature" qual="XYZ">20</attrQual>
                    <attrQual name="minimumTemperature" qual="PQR">30</attrQual>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">STORADE</attr>
                    <attrQual name="maximumTemperature" qual="FAH">80</attrQual>
                    <attrQual name="minimumTemperature" qual="ABC">10</attrQual>
                </row>
            </attrGroupMany>
        </pos>
    </party>
    </document>
```

I am using Below XSLT to convert the sample message

```
    <xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>


    <xsl:template match="document"> 
        <CatalogItem>
            <RelationshipData>
                <Relationship>
                    <RelationType>temperatureInformation_details</RelationType>  
                    <RelatedItems>      
                        <xsl:for-each select="party/pos/attrGroupMany[@name ='temperatureInformation']/row">                        
                            <RelatedItem>
                                <xsl:attribute name="referenceKey">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('temperatureInformation_details','-',attr[@name='temperatureCode'],'-',attrQual/@name,'-',attrQual/@qual,'-',attrQual    )"/>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                            </RelatedItem>
                        </xsl:for-each>

                    </RelatedItems>
                </Relationship>
            </RelationshipData>
        </CatalogItem>

    </xsl:template> 

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the current output is incorrect, it is having duplicate value of STORADE

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CatalogItem>
    <RelationshipData>
      <Relationship>
         <RelationType>temperatureInformation_details</RelationType>
         <RelatedItems>
            <RelatedItem referenceKey="temperatureInformation_details-STORADE-maximumTemperature-FAH-80" />
            <RelatedItem referenceKey="temperatureInformation_details-HANDLING-maximumTemperature-XYZ-20" />
            <RelatedItem referenceKey="temperatureInformation_details-STORADE-maximumTemperature-FAH-80" />
         </RelatedItems>
</Relationship>
    </RelationshipData>
    </CatalogItem>
```

The correct output should be as below in which duplicate temperate code is removed.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CatalogItem>
    <RelationshipData>
      <Relationship>
         <RelationType>temperatureInformation_details</RelationType>
         <RelatedItems>
            <RelatedItem referenceKey="temperatureInformation_details-STORADE-maximumTemperature-FAH-80" />
            <RelatedItem referenceKey="temperatureInformation_details-HANDLING-maximumTemperature-XYZ-20" />

         </RelatedItems>
      </Relationship>
    </RelationshipData>
    </CatalogItem>
```

Any inputs will be very helpful

Comment: Start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html Then lookup some of the numerous examples of Muenchian grouping here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Muenchian grouping to identify duplicates, a key could be

```
<xsl:key name="group" match="row" use="concat(attr[@name = 'temperatureCode'], '-', attrQual[@qual = 'FAH'])"/>
```

then change

```
                    <xsl:for-each select="party/pos/attrGroupMany[@name ='temperatureInformation']/row">
```

to

```
                    <xsl:for-each select="party/pos/attrGroupMany[@name ='temperatureInformation']/row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(attr[@name = 'temperatureCode'], '-', attrQual[@qual = 'FAH']))[1])]">
```